# Dynamic form with sections only adds fields to last section

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to have a form added to an html document on the press of a button. So far I have got this...

```js
var sids = 0;
var fids = 0;

function newSection() {
    sids = sids + 1;
    let id = "#" + sids + "sectionDiv";
    $('#formdiv').append("<div id='" + sids + "sec'><label><input class='form-control m-2' type='text' id='" + sids +"title' name='" + sids +"sectionTitle' placeholder='Section title'></label><label><input class='form-control m-2' id='" + sids +"desc' name='" + sids +"sectionDesc' type='text' placeholder='Section description'></label><br><div class='container' id='" + sids + "sectionDiv'></div> <br><button class='btn btn-primary' type='button' onclick='newField(sids)'>New Field</button><hr><br></div>");
}

function newField(sectionID) {
    fids = fids + 1;
    console.log(sectionID);
    $('#' + sectionID +'sectionDiv').append("<div id='" + fids +"field'><label><input class='form-control m-2 " + sids + "," + fids + "title' type='text' name='" + fids +"fieldTitle' placeholder='Field title'></label><label><input class='form-control m-2 " + sids + "," + fids + "desc' name='" + fids +"fieldDesc' type='text' placeholder='Field description'></label><label><select class='form-control m-2 " + sids + "," + fids + "type' name='" + fids +"fieldType'><option value='num'>Number Grade (1 - 10)</option><option value='let'>Letter Grade (A* - U)</option></select></label><br></div>")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="formdiv"><div>
<button onclick="newSection()">newSection</button>
```

The problem I have is that when I make a new section the 'New field' button on it adds the field to the last section, not the new section. I know this is because I'm passing the variable into the function on the button.

How could I dynamically get around it?

Thanks :)

Comment: Please provide [mre], with some HTML. So we can reproduce the problem... Use SO snippet feature.

Comment: I did? This is the code that produces the problem. To reproduce it you just need a div with an id of 'formdiv' and a button that calls the function.

Comment: Ups my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it like this:

Add class `newField` to your button and remove `onclick` event.

Add id to your button: `id='" + sids + "button'`.

Then delegate on click event to any element in `#formdiv` (you do this because `formdiv` is already in DOM) having the class `newField`:

```
$('#formdiv').on('click', '.newField', function() {
```

And then you can get clicked button id on click and save it, also call your adding function:

```
var id=""

$('#formdiv').on('click', '.newField', function() {
  id=this.id;
  id=id.replace("button", "");
  //console.clear();
  console.log(id);  
  newField();
});
```

Adding new filed is now with clicked id:

```
$('#' + id +'sectionDiv').append
```

There was some problem with adding elements to DOM and click events, couldn't figure what exactly. But that is reason why I had to delegate click to  `formdiv`.

```js
var sids = 0;
var fids = 0;

function newSection() {
    sids = sids + 1;
    let id = "#" + sids + "sectionDiv";
    $('#formdiv').append("<div id='" + sids + "sec'><label><input class='form-control m-2' type='text' id='" + sids +"title' name='" + sids +"sectionTitle' placeholder='Section title'></label><label><input class='form-control m-2' id='" + sids +"desc' name='" + sids +"sectionDesc' type='text' placeholder='Section description'></label><br><div class='container' id='" + sids + "sectionDiv'></div> <br><button class='btn btn-primary newField' type='button'  id='" + sids + "button'>New Field</button><hr><br></div>");
}

var id=""

$('#formdiv').on('click', '.newField', function() {
  id=this.id;
  id=id.replace("button", "");
  console.clear();
  console.log(id);  
  newField();
});


function newField() {
    fids = fids + 1; 
    $('#' + id +'sectionDiv').append("<div id='" + fids +"field'><label><input class='form-control m-2 " + sids + "," + fids + "title' type='text' name='" + fids +"fieldTitle' placeholder='Field title'></label><label><input class='form-control m-2 " + sids + "," + fids + "desc' name='" + fids +"fieldDesc' type='text' placeholder='Field description'></label><label><select class='form-control m-2 " + sids + "," + fids + "type' name='" + fids +"fieldType'><option value='num'>Number Grade (1 - 10)</option><option value='let'>Letter Grade (A* - U)</option></select></label><br></div>")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="formdiv">
  <div>
    <button onclick="newSection()">newSection</button>
```